# Audio Engines , do they work on CPU, GPU or DSP

Tags: audio

I have been reading design specifications of the audio engines. What I am trying to achieve requires performance and I want to parallelize.

Only and only while reading openAL specification it was mentioned very very shortly that if hardware supports than openAL will use DSP as well.

But I am curious for other engines as well and couldn't find information for wwise for example.

In general do audio engine takes advantage of DSP or even GPU maybe ?

Comment: It will depend to at least some extent on the engine. Instead of focusing on what *other* software does (which folks here might or might not be able to tell you, eg. if the tech hasn't been described publicly), try asking about the task *you* want to do, and how you can achieve it efficiently. It doesn't particularly matter what hardware Unreal or Unity or Wwise or FMOD use if the way they use it is unsuitable to what you're trying to achieve. So asking about your own problem or feature is the best way to get help that's actually relevant to your needs.

Comment: I am planning to use audio engine for applying beam forming on human speech. The thing I want to achieve is a simulation not a game. Since the subject that I want to use the audio engine very specific I didn't wanted to mention. Since it seems wwave is the only one supports multiple listeners it is the one which fits my application most.